# How do I parse using for-loop?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My aim is parse "funpay.com"'s offer page. It has to be easy, cause all offer names are inside the same class `'tc-item'`.

However I can't use bs4+requests, because this page loads only if you're logged in, which I'm doing via cookies (`selenium+pickle`).

Idk how to make it at all, so I'll appreciate any hints.

The code I tried:

```
driver.get("https://funpay.com/orders/trade")
soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

try:

    paid = soup.find_all('a', class_='tc-item')
    for sold in paid:
        title = sold.find('div', class_='tc-order') # inside 'a', 
                                                    # prints the code of offer
        print(title)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue, is there any error (whole stack trace)  or is something missing? Would also be great to provide an example of the HTML, if there is no chance to login. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the rather thin starting point, I suspect it's an error that occurs during iterations, so here's what I would do.

In order not to discard everything directly, check inside the loop whether the element you are looking for is available or not and let output the result accordingly.

```
...
soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
paid = soup.find_all('a', class_='tc-item')

for sold in paid:
    title = sold.find('div', class_='tc-order').text if sold.find('div', class_='tc-order') else 'no element found'
    print(title)
```

Comment: Omg, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for this solution, I wasn't even thinking about something like that!!